Why is adding kinetic energy to a closed system all at once different from adding it bit by bit? (Using finite difference wave equation)
I am struggling to understand something. If you add kinetic energy to a system where there is conservation of energy, why should it be different whether you add it all at once, or otherwise add it in a stepwise fashion over time?
Wave Equation
A wave equation with no damping is given by:
$$y_{tt} = c^2 y_{xx}$$
Where $c$ is wave velocity. This is a closed system with conservation of energy.
If you solve this as a finite difference model (ie. for a string fixed at both ends) and add kinetic energy to one node in the solution, why would it then matter whether you add it all at once or sequentially over time?
I have tested this and it matters a great deal, though I can't understand why.
Using finite difference model of the nature: $y_{tt}(x,t)={y(x,t+Δt)−2y(x,t)+y(x,t−Δt) \over(Δt)^2}$ and $y_{xx}(x,t)={y(x+Δx,t)−2y(x,t)+y(x-Δx,t) \over(Δx)^2}$
Simulation
I have written a simple C++ simulation which demonstrates the issue. This can be run on a free online C++ compiler by copying and pasting into one like this one.
This simulation sets up a basic string (eg. a guitar string) and adds a certain amount of arbitrary kinetic energy to one node. It then solves the wave equation for an arbitrary amount of time (120 seconds here), and for the last 25% of the simulation, it will find the maximally excited amplitude of the simulation, and at conclusion, debug that to the output.
If you change numFramesToStim from 1 to say 5, this divides the kinetic energy added over 5 frames rather than 1 frame.
In doing so, the maximum amplitude reached is dramatically different. Why?
With current config, you will get around $0.016995$ max output with 1 frame but $0.036644$ max output with 5 frames. With it spread over 100 frames you get $0.066329$!
Why would it matter whether you apply the kinetic energy over one frame or 5 frames? Which of these results is "correct"?
How can we reliably add a certain amount of energy over 1 frame vs 5 so the outcome is the same?
Code
Copy and paste this into a free C++ site and click run. Change numFramesToStim from 1 to 5 (or 100 or 200) and see the outcome is very different.
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    //create data arrays
    const int numNodes = 100;
    float nodes[numNodes]{ 0 };
    float nodes_1[numNodes]{ 0 };
    float nodes_2[numNodes]{ 0 };
    
    //parameterize stimulation:
    const int stimNode = 10; //node of array to apply stimulus to
    const int numFramesToStim = 1; //number of frames to apply over

    //"string" parameterization:
    float stringLength = 0.65;
    float tension = 70;
    float freqHz = 82;
    float stringDiam = 0.001; //roughly 0.042 inches or 1 mm
  
    //wave vel 
    float waveVel = freqHz * 2 * stringLength;  
    float waveVelSquared = waveVel * waveVel;
  
    //time constants
    float sampleRate = 44100;
    float deltaTime = 1/sampleRate;
    float dTSquared = deltaTime * deltaTime;
    float secondsToRun = 120;
  
    //distance constants
    float dX = stringLength / numNodes; 
    float oneOverDxSquared = 1 / (dX*dX);
  
    //string mass
    float linDensity = tension/waveVelSquared;
    float csa = 3.14159 * (stringDiam * 0.5) * (stringDiam * 0.5); 
    float density = linDensity/csa;
    float unitMass = density * (csa * dX);

    //SOLVE AMOUNT TO MOVE STRING PER FRAME ON STIMULATION
    float keToAdd = 0.1 * 4 * 4; //arbitrary amount of ke to add
    float kePerFrame = keToAdd / numFramesToStim; //divide ke over number of frames
    float velPerFrame = sqrt(2 * kePerFrame / unitMass); //ke = 1/2 mv^2
    float distPerFrame = velPerFrame * deltaTime; //amount of displacement to add per frame
  
    //store max output here
    float maxPos = 0;
  
    //run for requested duration
    for (int j=0; j < secondsToRun * sampleRate; j++) {
    
        //push back nodes array
        for (int i=0; i < numNodes; i++){
            nodes_2[i] = nodes_1[i];
            nodes_1[i] = nodes[i];
        }

        //solve per sample new positions
        for (int i = 1; i < numNodes - 1;i++){

            //solve main wave equation
            float u_xx = (nodes_1[i + 1] - 2 * nodes_1[i] + nodes_1[i - 1]) * oneOverDxSquared; 

            nodes[i] = waveVelSquared * u_xx;
            nodes[i] *= dTSquared;
            nodes[i] += 2 * nodes_1[i] - nodes_2[i];

            //if 75% of simulation finished, start checking for max node amplitude
            if (j > secondsToRun * sampleRate * 0.75){
                maxPos = max(maxPos, nodes[i]);
            }
        }

        //add stimulation
        if (j < numFramesToStim){
            
            //can move current node forward (but will slightly throw off PE)
            //nodes[stimNode] += distPerFrame;
            
            //or more accurately, can move old nodes back (so not changing PE / shape of string)
            nodes_1[stimNode] -= distPerFrame;
            nodes_2[stimNode] -= 2 * distPerFrame;
        }
        
    }

    //GET MAX STABLE AMPLITUDE OF NODES
    cout << "=====================" << std::endl;
    cout << "max pos: "  << to_string(maxPos) << std::endl;
    cout << "=====================" << std::endl;

    //debug node positions
    for (int i = 1; i < numNodes - 1; i++) {
        string output = "NODE " + to_string(i) + ": " + to_string(nodes[i]);
        cout << output << std::endl;
    }

    //debug courant
    cout << "courant: " << to_string(waveVel * deltaTime / dX) <<std::endl;

    //end of program
    return 0;
}


I suspect this is related to how you actually do things in your code, not to a fundamental law of physics about adding energy. If I may give a suggestion, I think changing the title (to clarify you're doing a simulation) and trying to briefly describe what the code does will make it more likely that you get an answer.

The code is pretty straight forward to read even if you don't read code. It is a basic finite difference model of the simplest wave equation. 100 lines. If there is some problem you think is present there, can you tell me what? I can't understand the issue.

Are you familiar with the Courant Factor or other similar finite-difference convergence conditions? If you are not careful, you won't end up with anything resembling an actual solution to the wave equation.

My understanding is courant = waveVel * dT/ dX which must be <1. In this simulation it is 0.37. You can lower this even further by increasing the sampleRate. I added a debug out for the value in the code. But perhaps this is the issue? Ie. Courant is valid for stable wave equation, not wave equation with external stimulation? It is my only theory.

Just to clarify - the equation and simulation is perfectly stable over time. You can set the duration to 240 seconds, 800 seconds - it will not destabilize. And in the case where you are adding the KE as one initial sample only - this is just the equivalent of starting the model where one point already has some velocity. This should not be a problem I can't imagine.

The way you add kinetic energy is not doing what you want it to do.
From your code:
    float keToAdd = 0.1 * 4 * 4; //arbitrary amount of ke to add
    float kePerFrame = keToAdd / numFramesToStim; //divide ke over number of frames
    float velPerFrame = sqrt(2 * kePerFrame / unitMass); //ke = 1/2 mv^2

To summarize, you picked an arbitrary amount $E$ of kinetic energy to add to the node. You wanted to divide the addition of this energy into $n$ frames; thus, you wanted to add $E/n$ energy per frame. You computed that increasing the velocity of the string from its initial velocity $v$ to $v + \Delta v$, where
$$\Delta v = \sqrt{\frac{2E}{mn}},$$
would add this amount of energy.
However, this is only true when the initial velocity $v$ is zero, which is only the case in the first time step. In fact, when the string increases in velocity from $v$ to $v + \Delta v$, the kinetic energy actually increases from $$\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$ to
$$\frac{1}{2}m(v+\Delta v)^2 = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 + v\sqrt{\frac{2Em}{n}} + \frac{E}{n},$$ while you were hoping to increase it just to
$$\frac{1}{2}mv^2 + \frac{E}{n}.$$ So you end up adding too much energy in each subsequent timestamp.

Oh my gosh that is brilliant! Thank you so much. That makes perfect sense. I didn't think of that at all. Thanks again. :)
